# Linq Left Join Fails on List when right side is empty

Tags: c#, .net, linq, left-join

I'm trying to perform a left join on 2 lists, I'm running into a problem with my query where the left join fails if the right list is empty. How can I change the query so the left join will still work even if the list is empty

Example query:

```
var received = new List<Foo>{new Foo{ProductId=1,WarehouseSectionId=2, qty= 7}};
var reserved = new List<Foo>{};
var leftOuterJoin = from r in received
                    join rs in reserved.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    on new {a = r.ProductId, b = r.WarehouseSectionId } equals new { a = rs.ProductId, b =  rs.WarehouseSectionId } into joinedL
                    from rs in joinedL.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new Foo{
                    qty =  rs != null ? r.qty + rs.qty: r.qty};
```

.NetFiddle Implementing the problem
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Brh74F

Right now I can avoid this issue with a if statement but I would really like to be able to implement a proper left join in pure linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.DefaultIfEmpty()` in

```cs
join rs in reserved.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The reason why remove [`.DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-5.0) as:

```cs
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmpty<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValue);
```

> Returns
>
> `IEnumerable<TSource>`
> An IEnumerable that contains defaultValue if source is empty; otherwise, source.

Since you didn't pass `defaultValue` to `.DefaultIfEmpty()`, it will return `null` when `reserved` is empty list.

And `select r` since you want to return data from the **LEFT** table.

```cs
var leftOuterJoin = from r in received
                    join rs in reserved
                    on new { a = r.ProductId, b = r.WarehouseSectionId } equals new { a = rs.ProductId, b =  rs.WarehouseSectionId } into joinedL
                    from rs in joinedL.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select r;
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YuS9LS)

---

**Updated**:

In case you are accessing **RIGHT** table (`rs`), you need to do `null checking` for `rs` **first** and next handling for null case.

Comment: really this is just a simplified query for example purposes, there is data I need to select from both tables, and some calc I run in the select, I will update the example to make it more clear

Comment: In case you need to access fields/properties from RIGHT table (`rs`), you need to check whether `rs` is null. If it is null, then do handling.

Comment: I'm checking in the select but that still throws a error for me, how would check before that in the context of the same query?

Comment: Same, remove `.DefaultIfEmpty()` from `join rs in reserved.DefaultIfEmpty()`. [Sample demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x0vzjt)

Comment: Why is it that we don't need to provide a default value for from rs in joinedL.DefaultIfEmpty(), but we need to pass in one for reserved.DefaultIfEmpty()? It is a bit confusing for me

Comment: Good point. If you use `join rs in reserved.DefaultIfEmpty()`. Your `rs` will become `null` and next line you are accessing `rs` (`rs.ProductId`) which causes the `NullReferenceException`. While `from rs in joinedL.DefaultIfEmpty()`, this is to perform LEFT JOIN, assigning `rs` as `null` when JOINED table returns no result. So in `select`,  you query `rs`  by (**must**) checking `null` first.